# Cannot run "ionic lab"

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I cannot run the command `ionic lab` or `ionic serve -l` because I get the error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8200

I've run:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
ionic start myIonicApp blank
cd myIonicApp 
npm i -D -E @ionic/lab
ionic lab
```

Then the error occurs:

> ionic-lab http://localhost:8100 --host localhost --port 8200 --project-type ionic-angular --app-name myIonicApp --app-version 0.0.1

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
> Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8200
>      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1343:19)
>      at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1510:7)
>      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:72:10)
```

**Versions:**

Node: v8.12.0

Ionic CLI: 4.8.0

Cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

I've also tried to change the port with this command: `ionic serve -l -p 27222` but the error "Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8200" continues.

When I run "netstat" it shows that a proccess svchost.exe is listening on port 8200. The proccess id corresponds to "System" proccess ("NT Kernel and System")

Anyone knows what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my local IIS. It had an application running on port 8200.

Answer (score 2):

you can also change the value  of DEFAULT_LAB_PORT in server.js and serve.d.ts
follow the steps to find the where to change the port

**Step 1:** get the location of your ionic , for this use

for windows use  `where ionic`

for linux use `whereis ionic` 

 it should display your global npm folder (if you have installed it globally)

```
D:\Users>where ionic
D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic
D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.cmd
```

**Step 2:** open the ionic.cmd(for Windows) and search something like this

```
"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic" %*
```

**Step 3:** now go to the `@ionic\cli` directory given above and open `./lib/sereve.js` change the const DEFAULT_LAB_PORT=8202 or by your desired port

**Step 4:** now in the same directory open `./lib/sereve.d.ts` change the const DEFAULT_LAB_PORT=8202 or by your desired port

**Step 5:** Run your application with `ionic serve --lab`

your application will run on new port

Answer (score 0):

That version just came out yesterday.   Several things you can check:

- Manually remove any Ionic processes that are running and try again.
- Kill any process with port 8200 open or Launch with different port Number.
- Run with Angular outside of Ionic: ng serve
- Use live-server: npm install -g live-server && ionic build && live-server
- Downgrade to version 4.7.1 or even 3.20.0(not the best choice)
- Upgrade your Node to 10+ LTS

Comment: I tried downgrading the ionic CLI. I didn't work. I managed it to work in other computer with an old angular CLI (1.x.x). When I run netstat I can see a proccess "svchost.exe" listening on port 8200. That sounds strange.

Comment: I upgraded the angular cli of my other computer and it still worked. I'm running out of ideas

Comment: When I run "netstat" it shows that a proccess svchos.exe is listening on port 8200. The proccess id corresponds to "System" proccess ("NT Kernel and System").

Answer (score 0):

```bash
//run
ionic-lab http://172.27.80.1:8102/home --port <any port number expect 8200 i.e 8300>
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.